# getLastRow() affecting other cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I am currently working on a time tracking system. With the following code I track the time how long a value was in a cell. This time is recorded in another worksheet and this is done continuously by appendRow ().

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2";
  var ss = e.source;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, 1000, 1);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) {
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
    var val = cell.getValue();
    var sourceRowIndex = cell.getRow();
    if (val != "") {
      let rowToAdd = [val, "", currentDate, ""]
      targetSheet.appendRow(rowToAdd);
      scriptProperties.setProperty(sourceRowIndex, targetSheet.getLastRow());
    } else {
      var rowIndex = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty(sourceRowIndex));
      if (rowIndex) targetSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 4).setValue(currentDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Now one Picture to show my Problem:
[image]

The problem is that the cells should start in row 1, is that possible with getLastRow ()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Determine the last row with content based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column) (e.g. column A):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2";
  var ss = e.source;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, 1000, 1);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws) {
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
    var val = cell.getValue();
    var sourceRowIndex = cell.getRow();
    if (val != "") {
      let rowToAdd = [val, "", currentDate, ""]
      let rowA=targetSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length+1; // new code
      targetSheet.getRange(rowA,1,1,rowToAdd.length).setValues([rowToAdd]); // new code
      scriptProperties.setProperty(sourceRowIndex, targetSheet.getLastRow());
    } else {
      var rowIndex = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty(sourceRowIndex));
      if (rowIndex) targetSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 4).setValue(currentDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine, except that the last date is entered again below and not next to the "start date". [link] (https://gyazo.com/18cd1dc6fd8fa1b576d6716acdba5db3) As you can see in this Picture.

Comment: @LamaFahrrad hmm are you sure that date wasn't there before ? The code is not supposed to add the date there. Remove it and try again .

Comment: Does it work for you? I tried it again with the same problem.

Comment: @LamaFahrrad replace `rowIndex` with `rowA`.

Comment: Ok in which line?

Comment: @LamaFahrrad I would say in every place .

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @LamaFahrrad replace also `targetSheet.getLastRow()` with `rowA-1` . If this does not work share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Now its working but only with rowA not -1. Thx

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to change the formula for Time to not display anything at all unless there was an entry, then getLastRow() will work just fine.  For help with that, share the formula that's calculating the time.

Comment: Formula to calculate the time is just =D2-C2 and so on in the remaining lines.

Comment: Try this instead: =IF(D2,D2-C2,)

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't change anything